# Custom types for React component - props not matching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a function that accepts 2 parameters: a React Functional component and it's props object, and has the following requirements:

- The function should be able to accept only one parameter, when there are no props, required by the component
- Typescript should complain when the component's props are missing, or do not match the respective type

`

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren, FC, FunctionComponent } from 'react';

function render<T> (
    Component: FC<PropsWithChildren<T>>,
    props = {} as PropsWithChildren<PropsWithChildren<T>>,
): JSX.Element {
    return <Component { ...props }>{ props?.children }</Component>;
}

interface FooProps { name: string; }

const Foo = ({ name }: FooProps): JSX.Element => <p>{name}</p>;
const Bar = (): JSX.Element => <p>bar</p>;


// Incorrect
render(Foo, {  name: 'asdd', a: '' }); // Passing. Expected to fail because prop 'a' is not expected
render(Foo); // Passing. Expected to fail because the component's prop 'name' is missing
render(Bar, { name: 'test' }); // Passing. Expected to fail, because Bar's props object is incorrect

// Correct
render(Foo, {}); // Failing. Expected to fail because prop 'name' is required
render(Foo, {  name: 'asdd' }); // Passing. Expected to pass with correct props
render(Bar); // Passing. Expected to pass because Bar does not require any props
render(Bar, {}); // Passing. Expected to pass because Bar does not require any props
```

`

With the current version of the code I'm able to satisfy most of the requirements, except the following:

- Typescript should require props object when is needed
- Typescript should not allow passing props that are not required by the Component

Not sure what am I doing wrong. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some misunderstandings about `PropsWithChildren`.  `FC` already uses `PropsWithChildren` behind the scenes, so `FC<PropsWithChildren<T>>` is redundant.  `PropsWithChildren<PropsWithChildren<T>>` is obviously redundant.  I think you would up having it twice there to fix an error caused by adding it to `FC`.

`children` can be included in the spread operator.  `<Component { ...props }>{ props?.children }</Component>` is the same as just `<Component { ...props }/>`.

In order to make the second argument optional for only certain values of `T`, you need to combine the generic with function overloading.

```
function render(Component: FC<{}>): JSX.Element
function render<T> (Component: FC<T>, props: PropsWithChildren<T>): JSX.Element
function render<T> (Component: FC<T>, props = {} as PropsWithChildren<T>): JSX.Element {
    return <Component { ...props }/>;
}
```

This does not give errors with extra properties.  I can tell you the reason but I'm not sure of the fix.  When you call `render(Foo, {  name: 'asdd', a: '' })`, it gets inferred as `render<{ name: string; a: string; }>`.  Foo is perfectly valid as a render component for that type.  It's assumed it will just ignore the extra properties.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the best option for the moment is with overloaded functions. The only way I could make this version fail with extra properties is with passing the type with the function call: `render<FooProps>(Foo, { name: 'Bob', a: ' ' })`

Answer (score 2):

You are using [typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) but how would you expect that TS will find out that `FooProps` should be used when you are passing in `Foo` as the first argument. Your solution would only work if you would specify the template parameter at the call. E.g.

`render<FooProps>(Foo, {  name: 'asdd', a: '' });`

It may be better if you take the FC argument as the template class. E.g.

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren, FC, FunctionComponent } from 'react';

function render<T>(
    Component: (_props: T) => JSX.Element,
    props: PropsWithChildren<T> = {} as PropsWithChildren<T>,
): JSX.Element {
    return <Component {...props}>{props?.children}</Component>;
}

interface FooProps {
    name: string;
}

interface BarProps {
}

const Foo = ({ name }: FooProps): JSX.Element => <p>{name}</p>;
const Bar = ({}: BarProps): JSX.Element => <p>bar</p>;
```

This would solve most of your problems. However defining the default value as empty object will not allow you to fail in case of missing argument as you must cast it to the right type at definition but it will ignore validation when not provided (bacuse the already casted default value will be used so it will never fail).